# Checking for a line of four (Connect Four in Java)

Tags: java

I'm making a Connect Four clone in Java and I'm running into some problems. I've done most of the code but I'm at a loss on how to check for a win condition. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConnectFour
{
    private static char board[][];
    private static final int BOARD_WIDTH = 7;
    private static final int BOARD_HEIGHT = 6;
    private static boolean gameEnd = false;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Element #0 in the two-dimensional 'board' array is not used
    // so that the column numbers selected by the players match
    // with the actual internal element numbers of the array

    board = new char[BOARD_HEIGHT + 1][BOARD_WIDTH + 1];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    char turn = 'x';
    int dropColumn = 0;

    System.out.println("TWO PLAYER CONNECT FOUR GAME!");
    InitializeBoard();
    while (gameEnd == false)
    {
        DisplayBoard();
        dropColumn = GetDropColumn(turn, input) - 1;

        if (DropChecker(turn, dropColumn) == true)
        {
            turn = 'x' == turn ? 'o' : 'x'; //ternary operator
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Column full. Please input again.");
        }
    }
}

// Set all elements of the two-dimensional 'board' array to spaces
private static void InitializeBoard()
{
    char a = ' ';
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
    {
        for (int e = 0; e < board[i].length; e++)
            board[i][e] = a;
    }
}

// Display the game board (the board itself, along with the elements of
// the two-dimensional 'board' array); note that the lines of the game
// board are NOT stored in the two-dimensional 'board' array
private static void DisplayBoard()
{
    for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < board.length; col++)
        {
            System.out.print("|");
            System.out.printf("%2c", board[row][col]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

// Get (from the appropriate player) the number (1 – 'BOARD_WIDTH') of
// the column in which a checker should be dropped, and then return that
// number; if the player does not enter an integer, report the error and
// keep asking for a column number until an integer is entered; note that
// the check for an invalid column number (< 1 or > 'BOARD_WIDTH') can be
// performed in this method or in 'main', from where this method is called
private static int GetDropColumn(char turn, Scanner input)
{
    int numInput = 0;
    int realInput = 0;
    while (realInput == 0)
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Player " + turn + "'s turn: In which column would you like to place a checker? (1-7)");
            numInput = input.nextInt();
            if (numInput < 1 || numInput > BOARD_WIDTH)
            {
                numInput = 0;
                System.out.println("The number was out of bounds. Please try again.");
            }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
        }
        realInput = numInput;
    }
    return realInput;
}

// "Drop" a checker into the designated column by setting the
// appropriate element of the two-dimensional 'board' array to
// either an 'x' or an 'o'; if the "drop" was successful, this
// method returns "true"; an attempt to "drop" the checker into
// a full column results in "false" being returned
private static boolean DropChecker(char turn, int dropColumn)
{
    int indexToPaceChecker = BOARD_HEIGHT;
    while (indexToPaceChecker >= 0)
    {
        if (board[indexToPaceChecker][dropColumn] == ' ')
        {
            //drop the checker
            board[indexToPaceChecker][dropColumn] = turn;
            return true;
        }
        indexToPaceChecker--;
    }
    return false;
}

// Check for a (horizontal, vertical, or diagonal) line of four
// consecutive checkers in the game board; if found, "true" is
// returned; if not found, "false" is returned
private static boolean CheckForLineOfFour()
{

}
}
```

I've tried multiple lines of thinking but I can't quite get it to work. How does one check for this correctly? It needs to check vertically (which makes sense), horizontally (which also makes sense) but the diagonal checks seem unnecessarily tough.

Comment: How would you do it by hand? Do the same in code.

Comment: Draw `board` on paper, with the indices.  How would you traverse starting from 0,0?  How from some other starting point?

Comment: This is a very interesting question (finding a line of four).  The naive approach will involve nested loops and a high degree of complexity i.e. O(N^3).  Later in your studies when you study algorithms you may learn dynamic programming which will make this search for a winning line more efficient.  For now follow the advice above to yield a 'brute' force method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if you're always checking immediately after a turn, you know the line must include the piece you've just placed. It's pretty easy to write method that counts the length of the line starting at a particular position, and going in a particular direction:

```
int lengthOfLineStartingAt(int x, int y, int xStep, int yStep) {
     char colour = grid[x][y];
     int i = 0;
     while(grid[x][y] == colour) { 
        x = x + xStep;
        y = y + yStep;
        i++;
     }
     return i;
}
```

This assumes that the cell at (x,y) is set to the expected value, and will therefore always return at least 1. You could alternatively pass in the desired value as a parameter.

While this illustrates the basic algorithm, you will need to enhance it to avoid array index out of bounds errors.

You could also save some execution time by limiting it to a maximum walk of 4, since you don't need to know about longer lines. Although the nature of Connect 4 means it's impossible to get a line longer than 7 (when your piece joins two existing lines of 3).

A line might start at (x,y), or might extend in both directions. You can get the full length with:

```
int lengthOfLineContaining(int x, int y, int xStep, int yStep) {
    return lengthOfLineStartingAt(x,y,xStep,yStep)
         + lengthOfLineStartingAt(x,y,-xStep,-yStep)
         - 1;
}
```

Try it out with paper and pencil to see why this is so.

There are four xStep/yStep combinations you'll need to try this with: up/down, left/right, and both the diagonals.

```
boolean isFourInARow(int x, int y) {
    return 
       lengthOfLineContaining(int x, int y, 0, 1) >= 4 ||
       lengthOfLineContaining(int x, int y, 1, 1) >= 4 ||
       lengthOfLineContaining(int x, int y, 1, 0) >= 4 ||
       lengthOfLineContaining(int x, int y, 1, -1) >= 4;
}
```

(Left as an exercise -- do this in a loop. Come up with a method that converts the numbers 0-7 representing 8 directions, into x and y values of 0 or -1)

Answer (score 0):

There will be four validations to check for a line of four.

1. Horizontal
2. Vertical
3. Diagonal (bottom left to top right)
4. Diagonal (bottom right to top left)

The approach to all four validations are the same; scan all possible starting points, and look at 4 consecutive pieces in a particular direction.  The key to understanding is:

1. What are the bounds on the starting row and col counter?  For example, checking for a horizontal win has no restrictions on which rows you check (you must check all of them), however you must take care when looking for 4 consecutive pieces pieces within a row not to go outside the bounds of the array.
2. The direction of the search dictates what the offsets to use when looking for 4 consecutive pieces

So looking for a diagonal win is very similar to a vertical or horizontal approach.  Here is a brute force way to check validation #3 above; the others are small variations and left as an exercise for you.

```
private static boolean checkForLineOfFour(char turn) {
    // Diagonal (bottom left to top right)
    for (int row = board.length-1; row >= 3; row--) {
        for (int col = 0; col <= board.length-4; col++) {
            boolean isLine = true;
            for (int i = 0; i<4 && isLine; i++) {
                if (board[row-i][col+i] != turn)
                    isLine = false;
            }
            if (isLine)
                return true;
        }
    }

    // TODO:  Diagonal (bottom right to top left)
    // TODO:  Vertical
    // TODO:  Horizontal

    return false;
}
```

Then alter your program to check for a win each turn:

```
if (DropChecker(turn, dropColumn) == true) {
    if (checkForLineOfFour(turn)) {
        DisplayBoard();
        System.out.println("Winner="+turn);
        gameEnd = true;
    }
    turn = 'x' == turn ? 'o' : 'x'; // ternary operator
}
```